# Powershell throw error on deleting a directory

Tags: powershell

I am trying to delete a large size directory using the following command: ( rajkaml is folder name )

```
rmdir /s /q rajkamal
```

But getting error as :

```
Remove-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '.\rajkamal'.
At line:1 char:6
+ rmdir <<<<  /s/q .\rajkamal
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Remove-Item], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
```

How to fix it? what is wrong with my command?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're trying to run `rmdir` within PowerShell you're not running what you think you're running.

If you run `rmdir -?` you will see that it's just an alias to Remove-Item which doesn't support the switches you've used. If I'm not mistaken the equivalent would be `Remove-Item -Recurse -Confirm:$false` or depending on it a `-Force` instead of the confirm.